# In SVD, why is V in the row space

Tags: linear-algebra

In Strang's book, on the topic of Singular Value Decomposition, when we have: $AV=U\Sigma$, he says that the vectors $u$ are in the column space of $A$, which is clear enough. But also that $v$ are in the row space of $A$. Now, why would that be?

For each vector, we have:

$$Av_i=\sigma_iu_i$$

So clearly $u_i$ is in the column space of $A$. But why is $v_i$ in the row space of $A$? Does it actually stem from the above equation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The row space of $A$ is $\{ x^T A \}_x = \operatorname{sp} \{ b_1^T A, ..., b_n^T A \}$, for any basis $b_1,...,b_n$.

Since $U^T A = \Sigma V^T$, $e_k^T U^T A = u_k^T A = \sigma_k v_k^T$, we see that
the row space of $A$ is given by $\operatorname{sp} \{ \sigma_k v_k^T \} = \operatorname{sp} \{ v_k^T \}_{ \sigma_k \neq 0} $.

Note that it is **not** true in general that the $v_k^T$ are in the row space of $A$, what is true is that the row space of $A$ is contained in the span of the $v_k^T$.

Comment: In  $\{ x^T A \}_x$, what does the subscript $x$ mean?

Comment: It means all vectors of the form $x^T A$, where $x$ is arbitrary (as in $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$).

Comment: Sorry, the notation $e_k$ is also unclear. Where do these vectors come from and what are they?

Comment: It is a fairly standard notation for a unit vector in the 'k' direction, for example, $e_1 = (1,0,0,....,0)^T$, $e_2 = (0,1,0,....,0)^T$.

Comment: Ah, right, thanks. Can you explain why you introduced them here, though? Is that to select individual $u_k$s from $U$?

Comment: The $e_k$ form a basis for $\mathbb{R}^n$, and $e_k^T U^T = u_k$, so we get the nice form above,. The same is true of the form you have in your question, since $V e_k = v_k$.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is simple: We have
\begin{equation}
AV = U \Sigma \Rightarrow A = U \Sigma V^T \Rightarrow A^T = V \Sigma U^T.
\end{equation}
Thus, as you know, columns of $V$ are in the column space of $A^T$, equivalently columns of $V$ are in the row space of $A$.

Comment: Just $A^T=V\Sigma U^T$ doesn't directly mean the columns of $V$ are in the column space of $A^T$, does it? I mean, $A=BC$ doesn't mean the columns of $B$ are in the column space of $A$.

Answer (score 0):

This depends on which singular values the vectors in V corresponds to.

---

If you have a **reduced singular value decomposition** then this is certainly true for every vector $v$, as each vector v has a non-zero singular value, this implies that:

$A^{T}Av = \sigma^2v$

And therefore this implies that $Av \neq 0$, which means that $v$ does not live in $A$'s null space. Now since $\mathbb{R}^m = col(A) \oplus null(A)$, we know that $v$ must live in A's row space.

---

This is **not true for any $v$ in a non-reduced singular value decomposition** as in that case there are such $v$ that $A^{T}Av = 0$ and for these since we know $v \neq 0$ it means these live in $null(A)$ exclusively.

(Additionally, from the above and the fact we know these vectors are linearly independent, the first $r$ vectors form a basis for $row(A)$ and the last $n-r$ form a basis for null(A))

---

I suspect that the question actually asks for the first $r$ vectors in V that correspond to non-zero singular values.

Comment: $V$ is always in the row space of $A$, so your claim is not true. For proof see my answer.

Comment: No I am pretty sure my answer is correct and coincides with @copper.hat, additionally I don't see where it says that at all in your proof. Please point out where exactly in my proof you disagree!

Comment: You are right, your answer is good, thanks.